# Is there a recommended way to retrieve information about the current recipient in EXM?

Tags: xdb, exm

As the title says. If I have some logic to run that requires information about the current contact / recipient an email is being sent to, e.g. contact facets, what is the best way to get a hold of that contact profile?

Comment: Can you explain further about what you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to add extra information to the email from the Contact's profile?

Comment: Also what version of EXM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EXM utilizes Sitecore's own rendering system to create each message. In doing so, the Dispatch server will make a call to the content delivery role to display the email through an HTTP call. It does so by passing in a handful of arguments, of which include both Message ID and Contact in EXM's `GetBody()` method.

This process then emulates as the user, meaning when Sitecore renders the components on the email, it's doing so, just like if it were drawing to a web page.

Therefore all aspects of the Sitecore Context, as well as Analytics context, exists.

That means we can retrieve the Sitecore Contact by using normal API methods.

`Tracking.Current.Contact` should reveal the contact that the message is being built for.

From there, you can access the Contact Facets through normal means.

If you're using a shared layout, you can use the following method to determine whether a sublayout is rendering for a normal page request or EXM is requesting a message body, use:

`Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Util.IsMessageBodyRequest()`