# Tracker.Current is NULL inside email in EXM

Tags: exm, sitecore-forms, tracking

I currently have a Sitecore form that has only one field, an email field. When submitted it sends an automated email to the email address inputted by the user. In the email body, I have a controller rendering that calls a view. The controller rendering has some logic in code behind that requires the current contact. I should be able get the contact through the use of an identifier as stated in this [documentation](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-platform/en/get-contacts.html) The Identifier I've used is the `Tracker.Current.ContactId`, I need to get this contactId in the controller but my biggest hurdle is that the `Tracker.Current` is NULL when the email is being sent resulting to the logic being skipped.

I expect that I would be able to get the GUID when I called the `Tracker.Current.ContactId` from the controller. It was stated in an answer as well [here](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/4078/is-there-a-recommended-way-to-retrieve-information-about-the-current-recipient-i) that the Tracker.Current should be accessible. How come I am unable to access this?

I'm using Sitecore 9 update 1

Comment: The linked answer is in reference to EXM 3.5 and Sitecore 8.2 in which case Tracker.Current is utilized.  In Sitecore 9, Tracker is most likely null, and you have to fetch the contact from the Query parameters that are available when the message is rendered and fetch the xConnect contact using the contact identifer information available in the query params.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the Contact Id information from the query parameters in the request URL for the EXM message when it's being generated.

The [available query parameters](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/exm/90/email-experience-manager/en/the-exm-configuration-settings.html#UUID-c84a0a00-5387-07c4-3af0-c5d16797fac1_id__SitecoreEmailExperienceCoreconfi_body) include:

- ec_contact_id
- ec_id
- ec_recipient
- ec_subscr
- ec_message_id

### Example Code for fetching Contact from EXM Query String

```
        using (var client = SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var contactId = new ContactReference(Guid.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["ec_contact_id"]));

                var expandOptions = new ContactExpandOptions(
                    CollectionModel.FacetKeys.PersonalInformation,
                    CollectionModel.FacetKeys.EmailAddressList);

                //Get the Contact
                var contact = client.Get(contactId, expandOptions);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried fetching the query strings as you stated on your answer but all of it returned either null or empty when outputted on my email

Comment: You'l need to provide way more info then. Screenshots, code, etc.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I've created a new question about this error in this link https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/19703/fetching-contact-from-exm-query-string-returns-null-or-empty please check it out when you can